# AFNetworking Bad URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I'm having an odd issue here, and surprised I haven't found anyone else with the same problem.

I'm using `AFNetworking` to make a `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

It works the first time a network connection is made. However, the same code fails once a network connection is made and displays a 'Bad URL' error.

The weird part is, the app never even pings the server before failing, I'm using Charles to sniff all requests.

Has anyone else experienced this?

For reference, here is the code:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:JOIN_URL];
     AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

   // httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;
     NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@",JOIN_URL, getString];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request

                                                                                      success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

                                                                                          NSLog(@"SUCCESS JSON: %@", JSON);

                NSLog(@"RESPONSE URL: %@",response.URL);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"FAIL JSON: %@", JSON);
        NSLog(@"FAIL ERROR: %@", error.description);
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE URL: %@",response.URL);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Cannot connect now, please try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

    }];


    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand `AFHTTPClient`, you provide it with a `baseURL` which is the **Base** URL to which all path you specify **will be appended**. And then when you provide a path, you only provide **the relative part of this path**.

So if you have a WebService at http://www.example.com/webservice/ which has some methods like `/listAll?n=10` for example, you will only provide `"listAll"` to the `path` argument of `requestWithMethod:path:parameters:` and a dictionary `@{ @"n" : @10 }` to the `parameters` argument.

*You already provided your `JOIN_URL` when you instanciated your `AFHTTPClient` anyway, so if you pass that `JOIN_URL` again in the path, it will appear twice in the URL built by the `AFHTTPClient` internally!*

Comment: Ah good catch, that will definitely cause an issue. his url would be: `server.com/server.com?getparameters` I would still escape your path string to ensure there's no whitespace in the get parameters.

Comment: No you don't need to escape the parameters as you should not pass them after a `?` in the path, but rather as an `NSDictionary` to the `parameters` argument. The `AFHTTPClient` will encode the parameters in this dictionary for you with the right encoding and percent escapes as necessary and compose the final URL using both the `baseURL`, the `path` and the `parameters` dictionary. That's one magor interest of `AFHTTPClient` actually, all those tricks are handled for you in here.

Answer (score 5):

You should really be encoding your URL `path` string like so:

```
NSString* escapedUrlString =[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I had tried. But it turns out there were 2 issues. One issue was a caching error that was server-side. Once that was resolved, this actually fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: While this may have fixed your problem I STRONGLY encourage you to consider @AliSoftware 's answer as the correct one. It is the way AFNetwork is intended to be used. He is right about there not being a reason escape the characters if you add them as GET parameters via a NSDictionary to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C:

```
[query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
        [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

Swift:

```
query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(
       NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
```